# How to customize item's bullet

Tags: moderncv

How to customize items putting this kind of bullet :

[image]

Code :

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,french]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}                
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[top=1.1cm, bottom=1.1cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
% Largeur de la colonne pour les dates
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{2.5cm}
\usepackage{babel}
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Smith}
\title{Graphic Designer}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\personaltitle{
  \def\phonesdetails{}
  \collectionloop{phones}{        \protected@edef\phonesdetails{\phonesdetails\protect\makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
 \par\noindent\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
 {\LARGE\textbf{\@firstname\ \@lastname}} \\
 \@addressstreet \\
 \@addresscity  \\
 Âge:\ \@extrainfo \\
 \mobilephonesymbol:\ \collection@phones@item  \\
 \emailsymbol:\ \emaillink{\@email} \\
 \githubsocialsymbol:\ \httplink{\@homepage} \\
 \end{tabular}\par%\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}\par%
}
\begin{document}
\cventry{d}{c}{b}{a}{}{ \begin{itemize}
\item aaa.
\end{itemize}}
\end{document}
```

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Manually you can do `\item[$\circ$]`.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid writing that line for each used item and that makes black circles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible to change `labelitemi` definition for all `itemize` environments placing them in preamble.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,french]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}                
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[top=1.1cm, bottom=1.1cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage{label}
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Smith}
\title{Graphic Designer}
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\scriptsize\color{blue}{$\circ$}} 
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item first
\item second
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**2nd version**

If you need `babel` can use `enumitem` and also define `itemize` symbol in preamble with `\setlist` command (page 9, `enumitem` documentation).

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,french]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}                
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[top=1.1cm, bottom=1.1cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Smith}
\title{Graphic Designer}
\setlist [itemize,1]{label=\scriptsize\color{blue}{$\circ$}} 
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item first
\item second
\end{itemize}
Some text
\begin{itemize}
\item Another first item
\item And a second one
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for response, but, the `babel` package is a requirement.

Comment: @dgs, do you mean `babel` or `label`? `label` is not a package.

Comment: @Sigur, Oh sorry! I haven't seen my typo on the posted code. It's `babel`.

Comment: OK. Another solution, if you don't want to apply the Ignasi's one to all lists is to use `enumerate` package and then you can use `\begin{enumerate}[\scriptsize\color{blue}{$\circ$}] \item  \end{enumerate}`.

Comment: @Sigur, I'm just trying to avoid writing that for each item.

Comment: @dgs, so the global solution above is the best one.

Comment: @Sigur, it doesn't work using the babel package.

Comment: @dgs, I have no problem here. Please, add a minimal code with preamble so that we could reproduce the error. Did you correct the typo in your file? There were only warnings, not errors.

Comment: @Sigur, there is no error. but using haven't changed anything.

Comment: @dgs, so you have something else affecting the result. Please, post a minimal code showing us the problem.

Comment: @dgs: New answer with babel and general item (with enumitem) definition.

Comment: @Ignasi, I've updated my poste, posting my full preambule.

Comment: @dgs: Did you test second solution with it? It works for me.

Comment: @Ignasi, yes. did that worked for you ?

Comment: @dgs: As I told you, yes. My second solution works with your last preamble.

Comment: that have finally worked !! Thank you very much !!

Answer (score 4):

You could also go with the [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package ---along with the [`xcolor`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor) one:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{Mycolor}{wave}{420}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}[label={\color{Mycolor}$\circ$}]
    \item One
    \item Two
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Naturally, you can set your color by changing the value I assigned to `Mycolor`.

Comment: thank you for response, I'm just trying to avoid writing that for each item.

Comment: I don't seem to understand... you still have to write the whole `\begin{itemize}...\end{itemize}`.  The only thing you have to add is the optional `[label={\color{Mycolor}$\circ$}]` at the begging of your list

Comment: if I have 100 items, It will be boring to write and to edit this line for all of them.

Comment: No, you don't need to write this on every item :).  As you can see in my MWE, once you declare it at the beginning, you just type a normal `\item` for each one of them.

Comment: yes, but for each itemize, no? If I have 11 itemizes. I can forget putting that for another itemize after 2 months.

Comment: I'm sorry, but according to what you want you'd have to redefine the `itemize` environment, which, as you might have stumble across, is not so wise.  I think it's easier for you to just CTRL + C / CTRL + V the argument inside `[]` when you need this type of bullets.

Answer (score 1):

After enabling the french babel language, I got ugly dash. To get these nice bullets back, I [copied the code from moderncv](https://github.com/xdanaux/moderncv/blob/453d6947cabe45ece5631456e1d0fc905b9d4998/moderncviconsmarvosym.sty#L35):

```
\newcommand*{\marvosymbol}[1]{{\fontfamily{mvs}\fontencoding{U}\fontseries{m}\fontshape{n}\selectfont\char#1}}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize,1]{label={\strut\textcolor{color1}{\marvosymbol{123}}}}
```

You can also use a full circle using:

```
\renewcommand*{\labelitemi}{\strut\textcolor{color1}{\large\rmfamily\textbullet}}
```