# How to make bullets in itemize larger and change their color?

Tags: color, lists, itemize

I would like this bullet (`\item`) to be much larger than it is now and change its color. How can I do that?

```
\begin{itemize}
\item aa

\end{itemize}
```

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64891/change-the-itemize-from-bullet-to-square and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822345/how-do-you-change-the-image-of-a-bullet-point-in-latex-beamer

Comment: Also, you can follow the guidelines in [How to correctly shrink the bullets of `itemize`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/119319/5764) or [How to customize item's bullet](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/182818/5764) (the latter is independent from [`moderncv`](http://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv)).

Answer (score 4):

This is easy to do with the `enumitem` package:

```
\documentclass[x11names]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx, xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize, 1]{label =\raisebox{-0.3\height}{\scalebox{2}{\color{Red3}\textbullet}}}

\begin{document}

Some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text.
\begin{itemize}
  \item First
  \item Second
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]